# how to display table for different user roles?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how to show a table for different user roles?

My database table columns:

`id user comment groupid`

My `groupid` values are:

1. admin
2. agent
3. user

but it is showing all table data for `agent` and `user`.

How do I do it?

Comment: Write proper and clear what do you want?

Comment: " Too Broad " & " Off-topic: Why isn't my code working? " Show us your code.  Show us your db table.

Comment: Please do not be lazy. Doing a google search for `php access role based application` will yield tutorials etc.Nobody here will help you write an app and send a zip folder for you. Maybe you didn't get the memo, but that's not how things work here on SO

Comment: `would like to know `  NO..! We Dont Like to Know.

Comment: @Guys let's pull the right question from him?

Comment: Hello, what exactly do you want to do???

Comment: user write comment and inserted in my table 1 which is id user comment and group id  value 1 or 2 it will only show either admin or agent table.

Comment: Do not add question details as comments.  Update your question immediately.  We need much more than you are offering.

Comment: im trying to do assign the user once user comment and example assign agent1 and it should not be visible to agent2 once it assign to that agent.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From {Table Name} where groupid not in (1)
```

1 as like admin group id.

other way to display

```
select * from {Table Name} where groupid in {2,3}
    here 2 = agent
         3 = user
```

Comment: table 1 user/login groupid and my table 2 comment groupid but my problem its i don't know how to make it show or how to implement my idea. or how to make two table see each other to verify the groupid from table 1 and table 2.